# How to prevent a popup from closing when clicking on it using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, popup

I'm creating a jQuery plugin that allows me to easily display a popup. In this case, the trigger element is an input and the target element is a div. So, the functionality is based on the `focus` and `blur` event. When the input gets focus, the popup opens and when it gets blur, the popup closes. I need the popup to stay open when I click on it and it closes because of the blur event I have set. I have tried to plug in the jQuery `off()` function into my custom `blur()` function within the plugin but it doesn't work.

I want to be able to click inside the popup without closing it, even when the input is on blur state or if someone can provide me with a better approach with in the plugin, that will be great too!

**JS code**

```
    /*
 * Popbox plugin
 */

 $.fn.adPopbox = function(target){      
      return this.each( function() {
          var enabler = $(this)

              function focus() {               
                 return enabler.focus( function(){                           
                             target.addClass('triggered');                                                           
                        });
              }

              function blur() {                     
                 return enabler.blur( function(){                          
                            target.removeClass('triggered');                         
                        });
              }   

              function popbox() {
                 return target.click( function(){                      
                            target.addClass('triggered');       
                        });
              }

          focus();
          blur();
          popbox();

      });         
  }


/*
 * Invoke Popbox plugin
 */

    $(".popover-trigger").adPopbox($('.popover'));
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
   <input type="text" class="popover-trigger">
</div>

<div class="popover">
   <p>Content to be showed!</p>
</div>
```

[Here is a preview](https://jsfiddle.net/f6mfxbbt/)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the event `blur` because when you click outside the input, it is first the `blur` event that is triggered and then the event `click` but at that moment, your popup is already hidden and the target is on what is below, ie the body.

You should also use the `click` event on the document to close the popup by inspiring you with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028037/4864628

Comment: I guess I'll remove the blur event and see what will work best and I'll check your suggested answer. Thanks!